# uninitialized local variable 'xAxis' used

Tags: c++, initialization, undefined

```
        float yAxis;
        float xAxis;
        float yWinPos = window->m_y + 16 + 28 * 2;
        float yWinHeight = window->m_iHeight - 2 - 8 - 26;

        yAxis = yWinPos + 16 + (i * 66) - 10;

        RECT TabDrawArea = { window->m_x + 8 - 90 + 1, yWinPos + 16 + (i * 66) - 8, 90 - 1, 66 };

        RECT TextSize;
        TextSize = Render::GetTextSize(Render::Fonts::Tab, tab->Title.c_str());

        RECT ClickTabArea = {
            xAxis,
            yAxis,
            TextSize.right,
            TextSize.bottom };
```

Every time I try to compile I get: " Error  C4700   uninitialized local variable 'xAxis' used "
I thought I defined the xAxis float, even tried setting it to 0. Clueless.

Comment: The compiler is correct. In the code example  `xAxis` is not initialized.

Comment: What part of "uninitialized local variable" are you unsure about?

Comment: "even tried setting it to 0" Are you sure? Because that's what you should do. Either that, or give it a significant value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere in your code did you define the value of xAxis. [This means that ClickTabArea will have an unknown value for xAxis.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable)

Depending on how your compiler options are set, you may or may not get a warning about this uninitialized value, and also depending on how your options are set, your compiler may consider this to be a fatal error.

It is always a safe practice to initialize your variables to some zero-value as soon as you declare them.

Comment: Please don't quote Wikipedia. The definition you give is language-agnostic and plain wrong for C++. Using an indeterminate value (such as `xAxis`) is Undefined Behavior, so you cannot say that `ClickTabArea` has an unknown value. For instance, your program might just crash instead of creating `ClickTabArea`.